# Перемещение обьектов по кнопке

Tags: android

Есть такой вопрос: В общем, хочу реализовать перемещение объекта по кнопке. Например, когда я жму кнопку  , то  какой-то объект, совершенно любой , небольшого размера, двигается влево или в вправо, пока кнопки на экране нажаты. Чтобы не быть голословным, вот пример:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFbNTeW1d_8

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такое на чистом java в андроид студио? Есть ли какие-нибудь методы для этого? Буду благодарен, если подбросите материалов,статей,или названий методов, для изучения вопроса.

Comment: _Чтобы не быть голословным, вот пример: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=XFbNTeW1d_8._ - вам мартышку с 404 not found надо сделать?

Comment: Прошу прощения,вроде поправил

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/android.graphics.canvas.php http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/surfaceview.php

Comment: Делаете свой view и рисуете на canvas'е всё что угодно. [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/136802/), например

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв